# Merge results in union all sql

Tags: mysql, sql, union

*Table A:*

```
Column1 | Column2
tableA01 | tableA11
tableA02 | tableA22
```

*Table B:*

```
Column1 | Column2
tableB01 | tableB11
tableB02 | tableB22
```

When sql using `union all` in these tables, the results like this:

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB
```

**Result**

```
Column1  | Column2
tableA01 | tableA11
tableA02 | tableA22
tableB01 | tableB11
tableB02 | tableB22
```

---

### I ask: It possible merge the results?

I want the results somelike this:

```
Column1  | Column2
tableA01 | tableA11
tableB01 | tableB11
tableA02 | tableA22    
tableB02 | tableB22
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your result sets are the same.  In SQL, result sets like tables are *unordered*.  If you want a specific ordering, then use `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result sets are the same, because result sets are *unordered*, unless you have an `order by`.  Because your sample query doesn't have an `order by`, the two are equivalent.

More generally, though, you seem to want to interleave the values.  You can do this using `order by` by doing:

```
select ab.*
from ((select a.*, (@rna := @rna + 1) as rn, 1 as which
       from a cross join (select @rna := 0) params
       order by <something>  -- You should order by something here so the ordering is well defined
      ) union all
      (select b.*, (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn, 2 as which
       from b cross join (select @rnb := 0) params
       order by <something>  -- You should order by something here so the ordering is well defined
      )
     ) ab
order by rn, which;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply order your unified results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM tableA
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM tableB
) Results 
ORDER BY Column1, Column2
```